# Incorrect Credentials

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

I create custom user model that extends from AbstractBaseUser. I try to connect this model with API using rest framework
the register EndPints, getUser and logout is working fine. But when i try to login user it show this message 'Incorrect Credentials'

i try to find the problem and I discover that method authenticate don't work for some resnes

This is My Code

urls.py

```py
from django.urls import path, include
from knox import views as knox_views

# import views
from .views import RegisterAPI, LoginAPI, UserAPI

urlpatterns = [
  path('api/auth', include('knox.urls')),
  path('api/auth/register', RegisterAPI.as_view()),
  path('api/auth/login', LoginAPI.as_view()),
  path('api/auth/user', UserAPI.as_view()),
  path('api/auth/logout', knox_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='knox-logout'),
]
```

custom user model

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager

# cerate user manger (replace old user Table with User Table that we cerated)
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, phone, password=None, username=None,is_staff=False, is_admain=False, active=True,**extra_fields):
        if not phone:
            raise ValueError("User must have a phone number")
        if not password:
            raise ValueError("User must have password")

        user = self.model(phone=phone)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.username = username
        user.staff = is_staff
        user.admain = is_admain
        user.active = active
        user.save(using=self.db)
        return user

    def create_staff(self, phone, password=None, username=None,**extra_fields):
        user = self.create_user(phone, password=password,username=username,staff=True)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, phone, password=None, username=None,**extra_fields):
        user = self.create_user(phone,password=password,username=username)
        user.staff = True
        user.admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

# Cerate User Model the will every user will inherit from it
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=9, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)   # Can login
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'phone'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    object = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.phone

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.username

    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_staff

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True


    @property
    def is_superuser(self):
        return self.admin

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.staff
```

API.py

```py
from rest_framework import generics, permissions
from rest_framework.response import Response
from knox.models import AuthToken

# import serializers
from .serializers import UserSerializer, RegisterSerializer, LoginSerializer

# Regester API
class RegisterAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):
  serializer_class = RegisterSerializer

  def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    user = serializer.save()
    return Response({
      "user": UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
      "token": AuthToken.objects.create(user)[1]
    })


# Login API
class LoginAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):
  serializer_class = LoginSerializer

  def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    user = serializer.validated_data
    return Response({
      "user": UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
      "token": AuthToken.objects.create(user)[1]
    })

# Get User API
class UserAPI(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
  permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated,]
  serializer_class = UserSerializer

  def get_object(self):
    return self.request.user
```

serializers.py

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate


# import user Model
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()

# User Serializer
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('id', 'phone', 'username', 'active', 'staff', 'admin')


# Register Serializer
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('id', 'phone', 'username', 'active', 'staff', 'admin', 'password')
    extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

  def create(self, validated_data):
    user = User.object.create_user(validated_data['phone'], validated_data['username'],validated_data['password'])

    return user


# Login Serializer
class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
  phone = serializers.CharField()
  password = serializers.CharField()

  print("-=-=-=-=-=--=-=-=-=--==-=---")
  def validate(self, data):
    user = authenticate(**data)
    #user = authenticate(phone=data[phone], password=data[password])
    # not comming her ....... why ?!!!!
    print("next !!")
    print("-=-=-=-=-=--=-=-=-=--==-=---")
    if user and user.is_active:
      return user

    raise serializers.ValidationError('Incorrect Credentials')
```

the API EndPoint return to me this

```
{
    "non_field_errors": [
        "Incorrect Credentials"
    ]
}
```

Comment: yes. I check from db and when i remove it it give the same result

Comment: add(or alter) this     user = User.object.create_user(validated_data['phone'],validated_data['password'],validated_data['username'])   in RegisterSerializer

Comment: How it works? Can you explain

Comment: i change the order of the function  (phone, pass, user) and it work

Answer (score 0):

In your serializer you are validating `phone` and `password` field but you are using django-authentication function to validate user. Normally django-authentication takes `username` and `password` to validate user but your serializer seems not have `username` field.

If you want to use authenticate function, first you need to find out the user instance associated with that phone field. One important thing is that as this is an unique field so if user exits surely you want to validate that user.

```
# Login Serializer
class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
  phone = serializers.CharField()
  password = serializers.CharField() 


  def validate(self, data):

    try:
        user = User.objects.get(phone=data['phone'])
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        raise serializers.ValidationError('Incorrect Credentials')

    user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=data['password'])

    if user and user.is_active:
      return user

    raise serializers.ValidationError('Incorrect Credentials')
```

Another important point is that you need to ensure your user is active.

Comment: it give the same result  ```{
    "non_field_errors": [
        "Incorrect Credentials"
    ]
}``` and when i try to print user object it return to me ``` None ``

Comment: i think ` user = self.model(phone=phone) ` that code is wrong ... in ` class UserManager(BaseUserManager): `